# ERROR AL CONECTAR

Tags: sql

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;databaseName=Comprobante using

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class DBManager {

    /**
     ++* Creates a new instance of DBManager
     */
    private String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Comprobante";
    private String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

    private String error;

    public String geterror() {
        return error;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {

        Connection link = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            link = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","1234");
            System.out.println("Se conecto a la base de datos ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No conecta con la base de datos:" + e);

        }
        return link;
    }

    public void closeConnection(Connection con) {
        error = null;
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = e.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBManager low = new DBManager();

        low.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: No hay mucho que podamos hacer con esto. La base de datos esta levantada?

Comment: se más especifico, ¿que necesitas?

Comment: No conecta la base de datos con el test de netbeans

Comment: Este es mi código

Comment: No conecta con la base de datos:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se pudo realizar la conexión TCP/IP al host localhost, puerto 1433. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto.".